# Probability of a polynomial to be primitive

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For a polynomial $F\in\mathbb Z[x]$ let $c(F)$ be the maximal positive integer that divides all the coefficients of $F$.

In a paper that I'm reading the author states, about the probabillity of for a polynomial $F$ to have $c(F)=1$,  that

$$\Pr[c(F)=1\;:\;\deg(F)\leq d]=\prod_p(1-p^{-(d+1)}),$$

where the product is over the prime numbers. The author says that this is well known and easy to prove.

I am having some difficulties both in find references as to prove myself. Can anyone help me?

For a polynomial $F=\sum_{j=0}^df_jX^j$ define $H(F)$ to be $max_{0\leq j\leq d}|f_j|$.  For any subset $T$ of $\mathbb Z[X]$ one defines the probability that $F\in\mathbb Z[X]$ of degree $\leq $ $d$ belongs to $T$ as

$$Prob(F\in T\;:\;deg(F)\leq d)=lim_{H\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|\{F\in T\;:\;deg(F)\leq d,\;H(F)\leq H\}|}{|\{F\in \mathbb Z[X]\;:\;deg(F)\leq d,\;H(F)\leq H\}|}  $$

Comment: Does the author mention what exactly the probability function is? Otherwise it's not clear how one should go about randomly picking integer polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial of degree $d$ has $d+1$ coefficients, hence for each prime $p$ the probability that they are all divisible by $p$ should be $p^{-d+1}$. So the probability that they aren't divisible by $p$ should be $(1-p^{-d+1})$. Now in order for the $gcd$ to be $1$ this must be true for all primes $p$, hence the product.

Now there are some subtleties to making an argument like this. As Jack M. pointed out in the comments, there isn't a uniform way to pick an integer polynomial (or even just a single integer) at random.  Nevertheless we can still make sense of statements like this by choosing each coefficient uniformly at random from $-N$ to $N$, and taking the limit of the probabilities as $N$ goes to infinity.  This is what is sometimes called the natural or asymptotic density.

Some things to take into account when you try to make an argument like this, and look at the probabilities for large $N$ A) the probability of an integer being divisible by $p$ isn't quite $p^{-1}$ all the time B) You don't even see all the primes, so you would only get a finite product, and C) The probabilities of being divisible by two different primes won't quite be independent.

Nevertheless these errors are relatively small for large $N$ and you can show that indeed this limit exists and agrees with what you get by considering the reasoning in my first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

If a polynomial $F\in\mathbf{Z}[X]$ of degree $\leq d$ has $c(F)=1$, then its image $\pi_p(F)\in\mathbf{F}_p[X]$ is non zero for all primes $p$ and is of degree $\leq d$. Inversely, if $\pi_p(F)\in\mathbf{F}_p[X]$ is non zero for all primes $p$ it means to non prime number divides all coefficients of $F$, that is, that $c(F)=1$. If for $p$ prime you note $X_p$ the set of $F\in\mathbf{Z}[X]$ such that $\pi_p(F)\in\mathbf{F}_p[X]$ is non zero and $X$ the set of $F\in\mathbf{Z}[X]$ of degree $\leq d$ such that $c(F)=1$, we just shown that $X = \cap_{p\in\mathscr{P}} X_p$, where $\mathscr{P}$ is the set of positive primes. I bet you can conclude from there.